# Improve Speed of Wordpress Taxonomy/CPT Query

Tags: sql, wordpress, optimization

Is their a better way of re-writing this Wordpress query to make it more efficient? Specifically the Join and post meta lookups

```html
SELECT 
    wp_posts.*
FROM
    wp_posts
        INNER JOIN
    wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
        INNER JOIN
    wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
        INNER JOIN
    wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id)
WHERE
    1 = 1
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'logofall'
        AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
        AND ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'criteria_id'
        AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN (1913 , 1909, 1910, 1912, 1911))
        AND (mt1.meta_key = 'student_id'
        AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = '999')
        AND (mt2.meta_key = 'skill_id'
        AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) <> ''))
```

Comment: google wp_query. It has meta query and has caching available also.

Comment: effectively what ive put is the output from wp_query. Im looking to take the sql wordpress generate and improve/optimise it

Comment: It would be very hard to say what will optimize it or not, it depends on the data in the tables, if there are a significant amount of posts and relatively less meta data you could query the meta data table for the posts you want, and then pull the posts from the posts id, but id doubt thats more efficient. TBH you may be better to spend time on investigating caching these queries and controlling when they are refreshed, or google scaling wordpress, there are plenty of tips regarding reducing DB size, etc